# TypeError: 'generator' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: arrays, numpy, opencv, reshape, transpose

Traceback Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\trial2\trial.py", line 56, in <module>
    image_stack(image)
  File "C:\trial2\trial.py", line 44, in image_stack
    reshaped = transposed_axes.reshape(new_arr_shape)
TypeError: 'generator' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

My problem in the code is that I can't reshape the array that transposed with a new array shape. The code takes in a path to an image which is read by cv2 and then the turned into an array. Using the length of the array the array the values for the transpose axes are calculated. Then the transposed axes values are used to transpose the array. I used `numpy.prod()` to a product of array values over the axes that were generated by the if statement. I wanted to reshape the transposed array with the the value of `new_arr_shape`, but I keep getting an error saying that `'generator' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

```
import numpy as np 

def image_stack(image):
    imgs = np.array(cv2.imread(image).shape)
    print(type(imgs))
    n = len(imgs)
    img = np.ones(imgs)
    val_1 = list(range(1, n - 1, 2))
    val_2 = list(range(0, n - 1, 2))
    print(img)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        y_ax = val_1
        x_ax = val_2
        axes = (y_ax, x_ax, [n-1])
    else:
        y_ax = val_2
        x_ax = val_1
        axes = (y_ax, x_ax, [n - 1])
    print(type(axes))
    '''The axes need to be in form of a tuple in order to be
    transposed'''
    if type(axes) == tuple:
        transposed_axes = np.transpose(img, axes=np.concatenate(axes))
        print(transposed_axes)
        new_arr_shape = [np.prod(img[x] for x in axes)]
        print(type(new_arr_shape))
        print(new_arr_shape)
        reshaped = transposed_axes.reshape(new_arr_shape)
        #print(type(reshaped))
        #print(reshaped)
image = 'C:\\trial_images\\9.jpg'
image_stack(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

> 'generator' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

This is because `np.prod(img[x] for x in axes)` returns a generator and the function `reshape` expects a list of integers.
To convert the generator to a list, use the `list` function.

`list(np.prod(img[x] for x in axes))`

`reshape` function expects a list or a tuple of integers. Also, the size (product of dimensions) should match that of the other array.

eg: `transposed_axes.reshape([1446,2842,3])` or `transposed_axes.reshape([1446,1421,6])` will work because the dimension of `transposed_axes` is (1446,2842,3)

Comment: I changed it to a list as you said, but I've got a new error `reshaped = transposed_axes.reshape(list(new_arr_shape))
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`